# Any way to distinguish between virtual and physical camera

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

Using Directshow.NET I have developed an application which grabs some pictures from camera and save it on disk. Everything is going fine but if in case some virtual camera is registered(installed) For eg. Cyberlink YouCam then directshow receiving following frame: (GraphStudio screenshot)

[image]

So, to avoid this I want to detect whether video device(s) found by `FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice` is virtual or physical webcam. Is there any way to distinguish between both?

Answer (score 0):

Physical camera are implemented by [WDM Video Capture Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390974). Virtual cameras mimic those, some - better and some - worse.

Those virtual cameras implemented without a driver do not typically implement some interfaces of WDM Video Capture Filter. The one implemented via a driver can be filtered out (black listed) by their hardware path. The task is harder with the latter because WDM Video Capture Filter wraps such driver and implements a filter pretty much similar to physical device filter, but hardware path should reveal its virtual nature.

Comment: "hardware path" means device path in graph studio? I observed that for virtual camera device path is : `\\?\root#media#0001#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global` and for physical camera it is: `\\?\usb#vid_0bda&pid_5776&mi_00#7&33f079c4&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global`. So I can check word "usb" with contains clause within device path of all found cameras, will that work?

Comment: I am not 100% sure here, but I'd treat those with `root#media` as virtual.

Comment: Yes, I mean first I will fetch all the video input list from `FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice`, then to keep only physical cameras in list i will check "usb" word within device path. As some virtual camera is not even having device path

Answer (score 0):

Use the following piece of code while iterating your filterInfo collection:

```
if(FilterInfo.MonikerString.StartsWith("@device:pnp:\\\\?\\root", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
  // virtual camera found
}
```